# Web Push Notification in nextjs using next-pwa

Tags: reactjs, next.js, push-notification, progressive-web-apps, next-pwa

I've been working on implementing Web Push Notifications in a Next.js project using the next-pwa package. I've referred to the official repository (https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/) and specifically the example for web push notifications (https://github.com/shadowwalker/next-pwa/tree/master/examples/web-push). I can show the live example also if anyone want.

However, I'm facing an issue where the subscription object, which I save for later use, seems to expire very quickly—sometimes in less than 5 minutes. As a result, I'm unable to send notifications after this expiration period. Is there is anyway I can get more expiration period or anything else in order to send the notification any time once user subscribe.

I would greatly appreciate any help or suggestions to resolve this issue. Thank you!

I tried using different browsers but nothing helped